# Metric of Einstein static universe (ESU) black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, metric-tensor

The Einstein static universe  (ESU) has metric

$$ g = - dt^2 + d\chi^2 + \sin^2 \chi d\Omega^2 $$

With

$$ t \in \mathbb{R}, \chi \in (0,\pi) .$$

Is there a metric that describes an eternal black hole in Einsteins static universe? If so, how does it lool like and are there any papers on it?

Comment: I doubt it, since the matter in Einstein's static universe needs to be perfectly homogenous and isotropic in order to not collapse. A black hole would disturb that balance and that universe would be no longer static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Einstein static universe (ESU) is an example of FLRW spacetime with dust matter and cosmological constant, so general techniques  for embedding black holes into cosmological backgrounds can produce the desired solution and some known families of solutions have static black holes in ESU as special case. Here are a few examples:

- Well known McVittie solution ([original paper](https://doi.org/10.1093/mnras/93.5.325)) has a variant with closed cosmological background and there the mass function and scale factor can be set to constants.
- There are *Einstein–Straus* models (also called “Swiss-Cheese models”): a spherical region is cut out from FLRW model and filled with  spherical region from another solution. To solve Einstein equations parameters of solutions and sizes of regions must be matched. A discussion and further references can be found in [lectures](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9812046v5). For ESU this another solution can be Schwarzschild–de Sitter and the matching conditions are discussed [here](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.38.2415).
- [Kayak et al.](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.63.024020) give a black hole solution specifically with ESU background obtained through another variant of “cut-and-paste” method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into the papers you kindly provided